# Magento Analytics user in magento2

Tags: magento2

I'm working with a new install of Magento ver 2.2.5. After the vm booted and i logged in, I saw a message `One or more integrations have been reset because of a change to their xml configs.`.

After clicking the link, it takes me to "Integrations" and in there I see "Magento Analytics user". I looked it up in the [Magento Glossary](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/backmatter/glossary.html) and [Magento Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/search.html?q=Magento%20Analytics%20user&hPP=10&idx=devdocs&p=0&dFR%5Bfunctional_areas%5D%5B0%5D=Integration&fR%5Bguide_version%5D%5B0%5D=2.2&is_v=1) under functional areas "integration" and don't see an official answer for this. Is it part of "Magento_Analytics module"? What are all of its uses? I see under API that it has access to Analytics/API resource access.

What is "Magento Analytics user" in Magento v2? Where are the docs that specifiy what that is?

Comment: I cant see Magento Analytics user in the list... brand new magento 2.3.0 installation... using all default values... please help

Comment: @user71563 is it required to create Magento analytics user? record in M2 to enable this advanced reporting Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used by the (Free) Advanced Reporting Module, which provides a dashboard interface to reports as well as improved metrics. Your data is shared with a third party service (provided by Magento themselves) which uses this account in order to gather the information it needs.

You can find some more information about configuring it at this site:
[Advanced Reporting](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/reports/advanced-reporting.html)

Comment: yungGuy I would like to enable this feature in M2.3.4 and found that there is no Magento analytics user record in M2 whether we need to create it manually? for this